# ReportViewer update via query in C# window application

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer, windows

I have a reportviewer displayed on a windows form. Report viewer on form load works fine. I have a textbox with date mask on it and a button to sort the report provided on form load by date entered in textbox. The button works fine but doesn't show anything in the report when clicked. Please help me where am i doing wrong on this one. Both images are here. [image]

[image]

```
SqlConnection S_Conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            S_Conn.Open();
            string query_1 = "";
            query_1 = "SELECT Select_Ward, Mr_No, Patient_Name, Date_Of_Admission, Date_Of_Dsch_Death, Disease from EO_System_RecordRoomData WHERE Date_Of_Admission = '" + txtbx_DateForReport.Text.Trim() + "'";
            SqlCommand Command_1 = new SqlCommand(query_1, S_Conn);
            SqlDataAdapter Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command_1);
            DataSet1 Data_Set = new DataSet1();
            Data_Adapter.Fill(Data_Set);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Data_Set.Tables[0]));
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Data_Set.Tables[1])); i was doing wrong only here Table[0] was used instead of table[1].

Comment: If you solved your own problem please consider either post the solution as an answer and accept your own answer or delete the question all together. Also, please note that your sql code us vulnerable to sql injection attacks. use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings to create your where clause.

Comment: How to make parameterized queries ??? Please tell.

Comment: [You can start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Data_Set.Tables[1]));
```

Instead of using table[0], It was table[1].